# Bunyan logger clean message before logging

Tags: node.js, bunyan

I am using bunyan to log all sorts of informations, errors etc. There are a few times when the log message contains sensitive information that I don't want to log. Is there any way to filter the log message in the bunyan logger before actually logging?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple serializer that checks for that sensitive info and deletes it before the logging takes place.

https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan#serializers